# Cannot remove string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have using this function to find if there is a specific string is there in the url if it is then replace it with '' and echo

```
<?php 
$url= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
if (strpos($url, '&cpp') !== false)
{
$url=preg_match("/&cpp=(\d+)/",'',$url);
}
echo $url;
?>
```

And the $url is

```
http://localhost:9999/store/product/manageproducts.php?category_id=21&cpp=10&cpp=0
```

But it doesn't remove neither it shows any result

Comment: You are double assigning `$url`. Take out the `$url =`. The third parameter captures matches. Also just put the `preg_match` into the conditional. `preg_match("/&cpp=(\d+)/",'',$url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` instead of `preg_match`

I have done it and its working fine

```
<?php 
$url= 'http://localhost:9999/store/product/manageproducts.php?category_id=21&cpp=10&cpp=0'; 
if (strpos($url, '&cpp') !== false)
{
$url=preg_replace("/&cpp=(\d+)/",'',$url);
}
echo $url;
?>
```